# Run main method of a class in the test folder

Tags: java, maven, program-entry-point

Tried to google but got hundreds of unrelated issues regarding testing. I guess I'm missing a crucial keyword to reduce the number of hits to something that is relevant for me.

I have a class in src/test-integration/java which i need to run, since it is a tool for extracting test data from an database. It's basically just a little script in the main method.

However when I try to "run as java application" in Eclipse it says: `Error: Could not find or load main class x.y.z.MyClass`

I know it has worked before, but not sure how I got it to work.

Sorry for any missing information, please feel free to ask for more.

Any ideas of what I'm missing?

Comment: Make sure your Java sources are compiled. Turn on auto-build: Project menu => Build Automatically.

Comment: And can you see `MyClass.class` in the output folder (most likely `bin`) in the folder denoted by the package?

Comment: does not end up in /target in eclipse. it does end up when i browse on the computer

Comment: That's ok, Eclipse filters out class files by default. Could be package changed since you last run it. Find your `MyClass.java` in the Package Explorer, right click, Run as, Java application.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do, as mentioned in the question

Comment: Run menu, Run Configurations. Find the configuration for running this file, check if everything is ok. Or simply delete it, and then try to run it again as suggested.

Comment: Tried to delete and try again, same issue. And your suggestion "check if everything is ok" I guess is what I'm having trouble with, but it looks good to me. 

I believe the problem lies somewhere in the buildpath, classpath or something like that.

Comment: @icza thanks for all suggestions, I fixed it now with help from a colleague, see my answer if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Added the whole full path to the java class in the Java Build Path properties in Eclipse and deselected "allow output for source folders" and selected it once again (don't know if that did something, but I include it anyway).

Comment: "Find the configuration for running this file, check if everything is ok." Specifing the full name of the class was included in my suggestion.